# I am trying to install oversip 2.0.4 on Ruby 2.2.0. but facing issues

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

At first I wanted to install `oversip`. I downloaded the source package and installed it locally

After executing

```
gem build oversip.gemspec
```

and

```
gem install oversip-2.0.5.gem
```

I get the following error:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing oversip-2.0.5.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
        current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/oversip-2.0.5/ext/stud
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180703-10042-1210kx6.rb extconf.rb
    [ext/stud/extconf.rb] executing system command: tar -zxf stud.tar.gz
    [ext/stud/extconf.rb] RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] returns "linux-gnu"
    [ext/stud/extconf.rb] executing system command: make
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
    libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
    need configuration options.
    Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
    extconf.rb:14:in `sys': [ext/stud/extconf.rb] system command `make' failed (RuntimeError)
        from extconf.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
        from extconf.rb:27:in `chdir'
        from extconf.rb:27:in `block in <main>'
        from extconf.rb:24:in `chdir'
        from extconf.rb:24:in `<main>'
    extconf failed, exit code 1
    Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/oversip-2.0.5 for inspection.
    Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/oversip-2.0.5/gem_make.out
```